# Identify negative sentence By using NLP

Tags: python, nlp

I want to check below sentence is either positive or negative please help me

Sentence -I don't remember anything

Comment: I think `nltk` can help you. Check this http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for? (In Python)

```
from textblob import TextBlob

TextBlob("not a very great calculation").sentiment
## Sentiment(polarity=-0.3076923076923077, subjectivity=0.5769230769230769)
```